# É possivel retornar um valor float com 2 casas decimais para final 0?

Tags: javascript, front-end, float

Estou fazendo um push para serem alimentados no Google Analytics e umas das orientações que os preços sejam retornados como float, até então tudo bem consegui resolver usando parseFloat(), no entanto, eles precisam de duas casa decimais até para valores que terminem com 00. Ex:(100.00 ou 208.00). Quando retorna um valor float ele remove valores que termina com 0.

```
var product_price = “100.00”; value = parseFloat(product_price);    
resultado = 100
```

Usei o metodo .toFixed(2) para colocar as duas casas decimais porém return como String.

Bom enfim, já pesquisei em vários lugares e todas as soluções que achei e as que conheço returno string. Acredito que técnicamente não seja possível. Mas gostaria de uma certeza.

Saberiam me dizer se é possivel retornar um valor com duas casas decimais para valores de final .00.

Só para deixar claro o parseFloat return um valor com ponto flutuane como 100.99, agora para um 100.00 não.

Obrigado.

Comment: E qual o problema de enviar a string com a parte decimal zerada? De qualquer forma, independente do tipo que usar, o Google receberá como string, pois os dados são enviados via HTTP.

Comment: O motivo é apenas uma solicitação do análista que cuida do Google Analytics, como não tenho conhecimento da ferramenta, tenho essas dúvidas. O mesmo informou que se eu mando um valor como string para o Analytics ele não reconhece.

Comment: Ou é float ou é valor terminado com zero. Não dá pra ser os dois. Se você explicar o problema verdadeiro, talvez dê pra ajudar (o que está na pergunta é um requisito artificial, o google analytics não exige "tipo numérico" com zeros à direita). Leia isto para entender melhor: [O que é o "problema X Y"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/70)

Comment: O float nada mais é que o ponto flutuante. Minha dúvida está bem clara:     "Saberiam me dizer se é possivel retornar um valor com duas casas decimais para valores de final .00." Eu preciso converter uma string para float e que se o valor for 100 ele precisa retornar como 100.00 e continuar como float. E se isso é possivel? apenas.

Comment: Somente como *string*. Numericamente não há diferença entre 100.00 e 100. Nesse caso, as casas decimais são meramente visuais e, por isso, demanda ser *string*.

Comment: Sim, sua duvida está bem clara. Só que ela parte de uma falta de entendimento da sua parte. É isso que estamos tentando explicar. Deixa eu tentar responder de outra forma: Formatação numérica só se faz em string, seja ela diretamente ou indiretamente. Espero que agora tenha conseguido responder sua duvida.

Comment: Concordo, númericamente não faz diferença. Apenas preciso me justificar técnicamente que isso é impossível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente com isso como prova

```js
        var product_price = '100.00';
        var value = Number(parseFloat(product_price).toFixed(2)); 
        
        console.log( value );
        console.log(Number(parseFloat(value).toPrecision(5))); 
        console.log( value - 15); //operaçoes aritmeticas funcionam
        console.log( value + 15);
        console.log( value + 0.01);
         
        //se quiser fazer somente se a float for .00 e nao , por exemplo 100.01
        product_price = '100.01';

        if(product_price % 1 == 0){
         var value = Number(parseFloat(product_price).toFixed(2)); 
        }else{
         value = parseFloat(product_price);
        }
        console.log(value);
```

Por isso sim não é possivel, Em JS nao existem ints nem float sao mesmo do tipo Number, espero que sirva como prova, mas nao deveria impedir operaçoes de forma alguma

[Cuidado com os numeros em JS (EN)](http://greweb.me/2013/01/be-careful-with-js-numbers/)

Answer (score -1):

```js
        var product_price = '100.00';
        var value = parseFloat(product_price).toFixed(2); 
        console.log( value );
```

No caso da para manter tudo que ja fez e acrescentar o [método](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) `toFixed(x)` com os número de decimais que deseja ter após o ponto.

Comment: O método toFixed() retorna como String. Mencionei esse mesmo método no texto.

Comment: Pois é. A resposta não faz sentido: pega uma *string*, converte para float, depois converte para a *string* inicial de novo. Três linhas de código para chegar no mesmo valor inicial.

Comment: Acredito que realmente não seja possível enviar o valor como float e que seja com esse formato 100.00.